# Почему CORS не оправляеться с Nest.js но отправляеться с консоли?

Tags: node.js, api, cors, nestjs

Взял для теста чтоб проверить общественную апишку jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```js
await this.$http.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
```

Получил ответ 201
Так проверил это не  у меня проблемы а у сервера.

Делаю такой же запрос на сервер

```js
 await this.$http.post(`https://primer.exe`,{
        "username": "Mana",
        "countFollowers": 1
})
```

Статуса никакого нет,запрос не прошёл.
Получаю такую ошибку

```
Access to fetch at 'https://primer.exe' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Пытаюсь обойти CORS

```js
await fetch('https://primer.exe', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"username": "Mana","countFollowers": 1}),
});
```

Получаю статус 500
Были попытки манипулировать  с хеадерами к примеру 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true но это тоже ничего не дало.

node ./test_api.js
{ status: 'success', task: { id: '49' } }

cat ./test_api.js

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

(async () => {
  console.log(
    await (
      await fetch('https://primer.exe', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username: 'mana', countFollowers: 1 }),
      })
    ).json(),
  );
})();
```

Так все отправляеться, в чём дело?